# COUNTIF running into problems with DataTypes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically I want to search 2 columns. IF any number in any of the columns is 1, I want to total it up.

here is my formula:

```
COUNTIF(('Background data'!$A:$A,'Background data'!B:B), 1).
```

However, when I apply it, I get an error saying 'Value used in the formula is the wrong data type'.

To fix this issue, I went to the Background Data tab and

1. Set all Columns to Numerical data type
2. Set all columns to Numerical data type in the tab that I am currently working on
3. Individually tested the countif formula with either column A and then column B and then I don't receive the error. This concludes that my columns are of the correct data type.

I am guessing I'm getting the error because there is an error in my formula and not the actual data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try breaking it up into 2 countif statements:

```
=COUNTIF('Background data'!$A:$A,1)+COUNTIF('Background data'!B:B, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to search 2 columns. IF any number in any of the columns is 1, I want to total it up.

A [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) can count multiple columns at once.

```
=COUNTIF('Background data'!A:B, 1)
```

Since summing a bunch of ones is the same as counting them, a [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) could do this as well.

```
=SUMIF('Background data'!A:B, 1)
```

Comment: I like your solution and comments better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

How do you plan on using `Countif()`?  Your formula, as above, has an extra number. Just use `=Countif('Background data'!$A:$A,'Background data'!B:B)`.

What's the extra `, 1)` doing?